# Pycharm does not show image preview on macOS "Big Sur" using OpenCV and Python3.9

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying to code a face recognition app using OpenCV and python on macOS 'Big Sur' and Pycharm, but unfortunately it does not show the image window/preview and it does not show any errors in console , below you can check code:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('news.jpg')

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img,
                                     scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5)

for x, y, w, h in face:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

resized = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1]/3), int(img.shape[0]/3)))

# cv2.startWindowThread()
# cv2.namedWindow("preview")
cv2.imshow('preview', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('preview')
```

I have tried adding cv2.startWindowThread(), cv2.namedWindow("preview") and even installed headless by "pip3 install opencv-python-headless" but it does not work.

Comment: the headless package certainly won't show you any GUI because headless means no GUI. is this issue related to Big Sur?

Comment: please post a copy of the console output from running your script. add a `print("hello world")` at the end of your program to make sure that console output actually works.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have read about it and in most cases installing the HEADLESS completely solve the problem, and there is nothing shows in the console, no errors, no prompts, absolutely nothing. I have added the print statement in deferent places and all of them been printed out in the console.

Comment: sounds like an issue specific to MacOS or even Big Sur. your code works on other platforms. can you check if the code works on previous versions of just MacOS, just python, and both?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes it seems the problem is related to macOS but it seems I solved it, already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line `face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`

with `face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascade + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`

and then it should work fine

Here's the final code :

```py
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascade + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('news.jpg')

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img,
                                     scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5)

for x, y, w, h in face:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

resized = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1]/3), int(img.shape[0]/3)))

# cv2.startWindowThread()
# cv2.namedWindow("preview")
cv2.imshow('preview', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('preview')
```

Answer (score -1):

Its seems the problem is related to macOS "Big Sur" framing system,

The problem can be solve by:
1- deleting the python env which I created for this particular project
2- deleting the "home brew" completely
3- created a new python3-env with python-3.9, OpenCV and "pip3 install opencv-python-headless" and it worked.